# Why do I have to enter 2 times in order for the code to work?

Tags: c++

I made a simple C++ program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string nama = "";
    string jawabsalah = "";

    cout << "Hai, siapa nama kamu?: " << endl;
    cin >> nama;

    cout << "hallo " << nama << "! apa kabar kamu hari ini? " << endl;
    cout << "Baik atau buruk?: " << endl;

    string mood_hari_ini = "";
    cin >> mood_hari_ini;

    if (mood_hari_ini == "buruk") {
        cout << "Aduhh kasian kamu, yang sabar yaa.. :c " << endl;
    }
    if (mood_hari_ini == "baik") {
        cout << "wahhh syukurlahhh.. ^^ " << endl;
    }

    cin >> jawabsalah;
    if (jawabsalah == jawabsalah) {
        cout << "Kok malah jawab " << jawabsalah << "? kan aku nanya nya baik apa burukk >< " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it seems that I have to enter 2 outputs in order for the code to work, which is this part:

```
   cin >> jawabsalah;
    if(jawabsalah == jawabsalah){
        cout << "Kok malah jawab " << jawabsalah << "? kan aku nanya nya baik apa burukk >< " <<         
     endl;
```

I know it is in Indonesia but can please someone help.

Comment: `if (jawabsalah == jawabsalah) {`  I don't know the language however this if statement is very odd. Of course the variable `jawabsalah` is always equal to itself.

Comment: You need to provide input that reproduces the alleged problem, along with any relevant output produced. This is part of [mre] requirements. It's quite possible to be something fixable by using `std::getline` instead of using the formatted input for strings. Usually, you want to use end-of-line to delimit inputs, not any whitespace character. Note that the test `if(jawabsalah == jawabsalah)` is completely pointless, as it will always be true.

Comment: *** i thought the last part was supposed to be the detail of the problems sorry*** You normally are supposed to show the output and expected output however until you explain the if () statement I mentioned I am not sure what advice I can give you.

Comment: You may want to do: `#include <string>`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Providing the necessary details, including your MCRE, compiler warnings and associated errors, and sample data if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by [paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1553090/paddy):

> It's quite possible to be something fixable by using `std::getline` instead of using the formatted input for strings. Usually, you want to use end-of-line to delimit inputs, not any whitespace character.

The reason you could be having to enter 2 times is because you are putting a space in your input, and you should not use this with `cin`.

In that case you would want to do something like:

```
getline(cin, nama);
```

It also doesn't look like you're asking a prompt before this part:

```
// cout << "?????"
cin >> jawabsalah;
```

And as several have noted, you probably don't need the `if` statement, since it will always be `true`, try to compare with something different:

```
if (jawabsalah == "example") {
    cout << "Kok malah jawab " << jawabsalah << "? kan aku nanya nya baik apa burukk >< " << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cin >> jawabsalah;` reads a string, so of course you need to enter a second one.
(And `jawabsalah == jawabsalah` is always true.)

Based on some quick online translation, I'm guessing that you want the last output ("I asked whether it was good or bad") if `mood_hari_ini` is neither `"buruk"` nor `"baik"`.

Do this by using an `else` branch with your conditionals:

```
if (mood_hari_ini == "buruk") {
    cout << "Aduhh kasian kamu, yang sabar yaa.. :c " << endl;
}
else if (mood_hari_ini == "baik") {
    cout << "wahhh syukurlahhh.. ^^ " << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Kok malah jawab " << mood_hari_ini << "? kan aku nanya nya baik apa burukk << " << endl;
}
```